# PHP - Catch error?

Tags: php

I am trying to catch an error for my app in PHP any help? I'm not sure how to go about sorting this issue as I am pretty new to PHP.

Error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function SRP\App\App::onError(), 0 passed

Code:

```
namespace SRP\App;

use SRP\App\Librarys\Config\Config;

class App 
{

    public static function boot() {
        Config::loadConfig();

        set_error_handler(self::onError());

        if (Config::get('app.environment') === 'development') {
            error_reporting(E_ALL);
        }
        else {
            error_reporting(0);
        }
    }

    protected static function onError($exception) {
        echo 'Something went wrong.';
    }

}
```

Comment: You should add what base that code depends on. What is the namespace `SRP`?

Comment: `set_error_handler(...)` expects a _callable_ as argument. You _execute_ the function, without arguments.

Comment: Your method `onError($exception)` requires one argument but you're not passing any when calling it: `self::onError()`. To solve that error, either pass the correct amount of arguments or make the argument optional (define a defailt value, like: `protected static function onError($exception = null)`). The message is actually pretty self explanatory. When that's fixed, you still need to fix the issue @arkascha mentions in his second comment.

Comment: Start by googling that exception. It's telling you exactly what you did wrong. You didn't pass enough arguments to the function. Which leads to question number 2, which arguments are expected to be passed to the function? this can be answered with a VERY quick google search... http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

Comment: @arkascha comment should be posted as an answer.